# How to write Pyspark function that can accept an argument with a variable number of parameters?

Tags: python, function, pyspark, arguments, variadic-functions

I wrote a function I'd like to modify to have an argument that can take one or multiple parameters but I'm having trouble making it work correctly.

```
def get_recent_date(input_df, *partion_col, order_col):
  w = Window().partitionBy(partition_col)\
  .orderBy(desc(order_col))
  output_df= input_df.withColumn('DenseRank', dense_rank().over(w))
  return output_df
```

I want the function to run so partition_col can take a variable number of parameters. In ex 1 below, partition_col= 'event_category' and in ex 2, partition_col = 'event_category' and 'participant_category'. I've tried running this a variety of ways and often get the error "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str". Thank you in advance for your help!

ex 1: get_recent_date(input, 'event_category', 'event_date')

ex 2: get_recent_date(input, 'event_category', 'participant_category', 'event_date')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*partion_col` allows you to pass a variable number of non-keyword arguments, where `partion_col` will hold all your non-keyword arguments as a `tuple` inside your function. Therefore, you will need to unpack your tuple of column names in order for `pyspark` to correctly use your variable-length partitioning.

Replace

```
w = Window().partitionBy(partition_col)\
```

with

```
w = Window().partitionBy(*partition_col)\
```

and you should be good to go.

Replicable example:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import desc, dense_rank

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('spark_session').getOrCreate()

data = [
    (100, 1, 2, 1),
    (100, 1, 1, -1),
    (200, 1, 3, 1),
    (200, 1, 3, 4)   
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("col_1", "col_2", "col_3", 'order_col'))

df.show()

# +-----+-----+-----+---------+
# |col_1|col_2|col_3|order_col|
# +-----+-----+-----+---------+
# |  100|    1|    2|        1|
# |  100|    1|    1|       -1|
# |  200|    1|    3|        1|
# |  200|    1|    3|        4|
# +-----+-----+-----+---------+

def get_recent_date(input_df, *partition_col, order_col):
    w = Window().partitionBy(*partition_col)\
    .orderBy(desc(order_col))
    output_df= input_df.withColumn('DenseRank', dense_rank().over(w))
    return output_df


new_df = get_recent_date(
    df, 'col_2', order_col='order_col'
)

new_df.show()

# +-----+-----+-----+---------+---------+
# |col_1|col_2|col_3|order_col|DenseRank|
# +-----+-----+-----+---------+---------+
# |  200|    1|    3|        4|        1|
# |  100|    1|    2|        1|        2|
# |  200|    1|    3|        1|        2|
# |  100|    1|    1|       -1|        3|
# +-----+-----+-----+---------+---------+

new_df = get_recent_date(
    df, 'col_2', 'col_1', order_col='order_col'
)

new_df.show()

# |col_1|col_2|col_3|order_col|DenseRank|
# +-----+-----+-----+---------+---------+
# |  100|    1|    2|        1|        1|
# |  100|    1|    1|       -1|        2|
# |  200|    1|    3|        4|        1|
# |  200|    1|    3|        1|        2|
# +-----+-----+-----+---------+---------+
```